# Data Model pattern for history but quick to find most recent record

Tags: sql, design-patterns, data-modeling

I am designing a data model change, and it struck me there has to be a better way...

I have a "log" that has many entries per parent entity being logged.  Most of the time, I just need the most recent log entry, but I still need the older data for auditing, reporting, etc.

Now, the usual way I'd do this is create a one-to-many join from parent entity to the "log" table, then use SQL to find the most recent record.

But it occurred to me: I can chose the data model.  Is there a better design pattern for this?

Answer (score 1):

The physical implementation could use a log table that is range partitioned by date. Can use a rolling window where the old partitions are archived off or summarized into some kind of summary table. Table access can be transparent to the app, but access with date prunes the query to the appropriate partition (searches on the single partition being more efficient than on the entire table).

Also, since log data only enters the current partition, older partitions can be put into a "read only" state. Depending on the rdbms, this can have advantages such as only needing to be backed up once and excluded for future backups, being able to swap in and out on the file level, etc.